# Change colour for sliderInput

Tags: r, shiny

This is how my shiny app looks like:
[image]

The blue slider looks bad with the red navbar. Does anyone know how to change it to red? I'm using `shinytheme("united")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is similar to @LyzandeR answer, but uses simpler code and doesn't use any additional packages

```
library(shiny)

mycss <- "
.irs-bar,
.irs-bar-edge,
.irs-single,
.irs-grid-pol {
  background: red;
  border-color: red;
}
"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(mycss),
  sliderInput("num", "Number", 0, 10, 5)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: doesn't work as expected when you want to style 2 sliderInputs differently though.... still trying to find a working solution for it that actually targets them by a tag. Adding #num (slider's ID) before the CSS doesn't work, and 
tried also to put the sliders in a div(id = 'slider1' , etc and then put #slider1 in front of the css code, not working as i'd hope.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the easiest task, but it can happen. All you need to do is change the CSS of the default bootstrap theme that shiny uses by default. I will use `tableHTML` (allows you add a CSS file to shiny from the ui) to show you which CSS to change:

```
library(tableHTML)
ui <- fluidPage(
 tags$style(make_css(list('.irs-bar', 
                          c('border-top', 'border-bottom', 'background'), 
                          rep('red', 3)),
                     list('.irs-bar-edge',
                          c('background', 'border'),
                          c('red', '0px !important')),
                     list('.irs-single',
                          'background',
                          'red'))),
 sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:",
             min = 0, max = 1000, value = 500
 ),
 plotOutput("distPlot")
)

# Server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
 output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
  hist(rnorm(input$obs))
 })
}

# Complete app with UI and server components
shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

As you can see above (in the `make_css` function) you need to change `.irs-bar`, `.irs-bar-edge` and `.irs-single` and add whichever colour you want. I used the standard red. You can find a tutorial on `tableHTML::make_css` [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tableHTML/vignettes/make_css.html) if you want to find out more.

[image]

Comment: is there a reason to add the complexity of introducing an additional package and function (and tutorial)? Can't OP do the same by just adding this CSS the good old fashioned way into the app?